# C# Enabling/Disabling buttons using an array, Win forms/MVP

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, button

i have an array of buttons [42] in a c# winforms desktop application :

```
private Button[] _tabButton = new Button[]{button00,button01,/*...,*/button41};
```

Than, when i called the "Initiate" methode i just do :

```
for(int i=0;i<_tabButton.Length;i++)
      {
       _tabButton[i].enabled = false;
      }
```

that was pretty simple and logic.
Now, am newbie in MVP/MVC, but I did a little work in the code...
i create an Interface and implement it ,to get :

```
public bool Button_0 { get => button00.Enabled; set => button00.Enabled = value; }
   //...
   public bool Button_41 { get => button41.Enabled; set => button41.Enabled = value; }
```

also :

```
 private bool[] _arrayButton_bool;// = new bool[42];//an array of Button_0,Button_1...
```

So,my problem is : How to enable/disable the 42 Buttons, using boolean variables "Button_0 ... Button_41" inside the boolean array ".

If i say :

```
 `_arrayButton_bool = {Button_0,Button_1,...,Button_41};
 //... inside intiate methode :
  for(int i=0;i<_arrayButton_bool.Length;i++)
      {
       _arrayButton_bool[i].enabled = false;
      }`
```

that will affect "_arrayButton_bool[0]", not the variable:"Button_0", i know my question is ambiguous, am not so good in english,but please i did my best to have a little help. thanks.

Comment: Your approach is fundamentally wrong, you should first explain why you (think you need) to do this.

Comment: have you tried LINQ/Lambda expressions ?

Comment: you need to put them in list and then modify it using LINQ/Lambda expressions.

Comment: Sikander Hayyat, i'll try with Linq/Lambda expression later, for now i am trying with Michał Turczyn answer and it's what am looking for, thank you.

Comment: yes , there is a better approach , also i guess i don't explain what i need in good way, thank you  @aybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define setters like :

```
public bool Button_0 
{
    get => button00.Enabled; 
    set => button00.Enabled = value; 
}
```

so `Burron_0 = true;` would enable the  `button00` button. But the problem is, this is setter, so under the hood it is method, which you cannot simply put in an array. Trying to create array of those properties would only invoke each getter and provide bool value.

So it is impossible what you are asking. Cleanest way I can think of is to define method:

```
private void SetButtonsEnabledProperty(bool enabled)
{
    Button_0 = enabled;
    // through to
    Button_41 = enabled;
}
```